# android constraintLayout ellipsize text starting different offset

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-layoutparams, ellipsize

I have this android layout

(root is a constraint layout)

```
 TextAppearance.My
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
```

and

```
  <merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <myImageView
      android:id="@+id/account_avatar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/avatar_margin_start"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/avatar_margin_start"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/avatar_vertical_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/avatar_vertical_margin"
      android:padding="@dimen/disc_padding"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      app:maxDiscContentSize="@dimen/image_view_size"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:src="@drawable/quantum_ic_account_circle_googblue_24"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.My"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/avatar_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_end"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/avatar_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_end"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_name"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/account_disabled_help_tooltip"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
      tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_name"
      style="@style/TextAppearance.My"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/avatar_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_end"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/avatar_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_end"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/display_name_email_margin"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/account_disabled_help_tooltip"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_display_name"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
      tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/account_disabled_help_tooltip"
      android:layout_width="18dp"
      android:layout_height="18dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/help_tooltip_margin_top"
      android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/help_tooltip_margin_end"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/help_tooltip_margin_end"
      android:contentDescription="@null"
      android:visibility="gone"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/quantum_gm_ic_help_outline_vd_theme_24"/>

</merge>
```

it used to be:

a linear layout (horizontal) with inner linear layout (vertical)
Then there problem wasn't seen.

And it leads to a strange bug where the names are ellipsized starting a different text offset.

This cause that short names may be ellipsized and longer may not.

What can cause this?

does `ellipsize` have problems when `layout_width="0dp"` ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` line is problem. Have you tried chaning it to match?

Comment: layout_width="0dp" is not a issue. If you want to ellipse size end for one line than use android:maxLines="1" and android:ellipsize="end". It's working fine.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan but i already have this. see ` TextAppearance.My` style